# Microsoft SQL.Procedure Error Msg 137, Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server

I am still a student programmer and I came across this error I have been struggling to fix it no matter what i try I cannot seem to come to a solution may you please help me.

I left my print statements out.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Report
@CompanyID SMALLINT
AS
DECLARE @companyName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @companyNumber VARCHAR (13)
DECLARE @companyEmail VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @food_ID SMALLINT
DECLARE @food_type VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @food_name VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @expiry_Date DATE


SELECT  @companyName = companyName,@companyNumber =    companyNumber,@companyEmail = companyEmail
FROM supplier
WHERE companyID = @CompanyID
SET DATEFORMAT mdy

--Create temp table

SELECT *
INTO #tempSupp
FROM vw_ExpiredFoodDetails
WHERE [Company Name] = @companyName

-- add the printed column into the temporal table
ALTER TABLE #tempSupp
ADD
Printed SMALLINT

--set all values in the printed column to 0
UPDATE #tempSupp
SET Printed = 0

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tempSupp WHERE Printed = 0)

BEGIN
    SELECT @companyName = [Company Name]
    FROM #tempSupp
    WHERE Printed = 0 
    SELECT @companyEmail = #tempSupp.companyEmail,
    @companyNumber = #tempSupp.ComNum,
    @companyID = #tempSupp.ComID
    FROM #tempSupp
    Join vw_ExpiredFoodDetails
    ON #tempSupp.ComName = [Company Name]
    WHERE @CompanyID = #temp.ComID

    UPDATE #tempSupp
    SET Printed = 1 
    WHERE @companyName = [Company Name]
END
GO
DROP TABLE #tempSupp
GO
```

Comment: Copied this into SSMS and found no syntax error... Doesn't it tell you the name of the scalar variable you should declare? Maybe it's in the part you left away...

Comment: what kind of error you are getting

Comment: yes it does let me send you the entire error. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@companyName".

Comment: The sp compiles correctly when `DROP TABLE #tempSupp` is commented. There seems to be no error. Did you copy the whole part?

Comment: `DECLARE @companyName VARCHAR(30)` is declared correctly in your SP.

Comment: Yes, I did copy the whole part except for the print statements that i have within my code @Abhishek

Comment: Probably you are using @CompanyName somewhere **outside** this context...

Comment: One more hint: If you double click the error it should bring you directly to the  line with the error

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT @companyName = [Company Name]
    FROM #tempSupp
    WHERE Printed = 0
    SELECT @companyEmail = #tempSupp.companyEmail,
    @companyNumber = #tempSupp.ComNum,
    @companyID = #tempSupp.ComID
    FROM #tempSupp
    Join vw_ExpiredFoodDetails
    ON #tempSupp.ComName = [Company Name]
    WHERE @CompanyID = #temp.ComID
                       ^^^^^
```

Here at last line you use #temp table name that is not declared anywhere.
Also there is no need to drop temporary table created inside stored proc.

Comment: #tempSupp is not #temp